# Order items in columns by class with css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to get a list of divs ordered in columns by its class with css grid, but without JS.

Here is an HTML example:

```
<main>
<div class="A">A_1</div>
<div class="A">A_2</div>
<div class="B">B_1</div>
<div class="A">A_3</div>
<div class="D">D_1</div>
<div class="B">B_2</div>
<div class="C">C_1</div>
<div class="A">A_4</div>
<div class="B">B_3</div>
<div class="C">C_2</div>
<div class="A">A_N</div>
<div class="C">C_3</div>
<div class="B">B_4</div>
<div class="C">C_4</div>
<div class="B">B_N</div>
<div class="C">C_N</div>
<div class="D">D_2</div>
<div class="D">D_3</div>
<div class="D">D_4</div>
<div class="D">D_N</div>
</main>
```

And the desired output should look like this:

```
-------------------------
|  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
-------------------------
| A_1 | B_1 | C_1 | D_1 |
-------------------------
| A_2 | B_2 | C_2 | D_2 |
-------------------------
| A_3 | B_3 | C_3 | D_3 |
-------------------------
| A_4 | B_4 | C_4 | D_4 |
-------------------------
| A_N | B_N | C_N | D_N |
-------------------------
```

Is there a way to do this? I've tried using grid-template-areas but either I have to specify one by one, or the items in a colum get on top of each other.

If it can't be achived with grids, how could I do it?

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Css is a styling language, as far as I am aware, it cannot sort - you can order stuff in a predefined way, but not sort

Comment: you can only approximate this by using a hacky CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Visually** this can be managed with the `order` property but it's not extensible or dynamic.

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 2em); /* number of rows is required - so not dynamic */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.A {
  order: 1;
}

.B {
  order: 2;
}

.C {
  order: 3;
}

.D {
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="A">A_1</div>
  <div class="A">A_2</div>
  <div class="B">B_1</div>
  <div class="A">A_3</div>
  <div class="D">D_1</div>
  <div class="B">B_2</div>
  <div class="C">C_1</div>
  <div class="A">A_4</div>
  <div class="B">B_3</div>
  <div class="C">C_2</div>
  <div class="A">A_N</div>
  <div class="C">C_3</div>
  <div class="B">B_4</div>
  <div class="C">C_4</div>
  <div class="B">B_N</div>
  <div class="C">C_N</div>
  <div class="D">D_2</div>
  <div class="D">D_3</div>
  <div class="D">D_4</div>
  <div class="D">D_N</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you build your grid with flexbox, and the A, A_1, A_2, A_3 items are all in order when looking at them as they are returned like this, (meaning you do not have to sort them within their own class), I believe you may be able to use `order` property on the items. And you would have to set your `flex-direction` property on the parent to 'column'.

I threw a quick codepen together to show you that these all get sorted once you do this. From here you'll need to decide how to style your containing items, and make the grid system break at the last item.

https://codepen.io/brianespinosa/pen/XBQyyE

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes